# Outlook Windows Background Image Space Email Template

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I am trying to get rid of a space at the right hand side of my banner image in my email template.  I have tried things from this [background image guide](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/html-background-images-in-email/#vml) but I cannot get rid of this space:

[image: Banner image gap]

Here is my markup:

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; min-width: 100%; background-color: #dde0e1;">

   <!--[if (gte mso 9|(IE))]>
      <style type="text/css">
         body {background-color: #dde0e1!important;}
         body, table, td, p, a {font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Helvitica!important;}
      </style>
   <![endif]-->

   <center style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; background-color: #dde0e1; padding-bottom: 40px;">

      <div style="max-width: 600px; background-color: #fafdfe; box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);">

         <div style="font-size: 0px; color: #fafdfe; line-height: 1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; display: none; max-width: 0px; max-height: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all">
            9 week overdue notice / Rhybudd bod eich llyfr/llyfrau 9 wythnos yn hwyr
         </div>

         <!--[if (gte mso 9|(IE))]>
            <table width="600" align="center" style="border-spacing: 0px; color: #565656;">
               <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 0px">
         <![endif]-->

         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="border-spacing: 0px; color: #565656; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, Arial, Helvitica!important; background-color: #fafdfe; Margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; max-width: 600px;" role="presentation">

<!-- START SOCIAL ICONS -->
            <tr>
               <td style="padding: 0;">

                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="darkmode-social" width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0; background-color: #60C1CB;" role="presentation">
                     <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center; padding: 10px 0 8px 0;">
                           <a href="*" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/k9vM0n0/white-facebook.png" width="32" alt="FaceBook" title="FaceBook" border="0"></a>
                           <a href="*" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/N9m4YDb/white-twitter.png" width="32" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter" border="0"></a>
                           <a href="*" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/qJ9R652/white-instagram.png" width="32" alt="Instagram" title="Instagram" border="0"></a>
                           <a href="*" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/jLDDZH2/white-youtube.png" width="32" alt="YouTube" title="YouTube" border="0"></a>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>

               </td>
            </tr>
<!-- END SOCIAL ICONS -->

<!-- START BANNER -->
            <tr>
               <td background="https://i.ibb.co/QKH3gst/Aura-banner.png" width="600" height="329" style="background-position: center top; font-size: 0;">
                  
                  <!--[if (gte mso 9|(IE))]>
                     <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:450pt; height:247pt; border: 0; display: inline-block;">
                     <v:fill type="frame" src="https://i.ibb.co/QKH3gst/Aura-banner.png" />
                     <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">

                  <![endif]-->
                  <!--[if (gte mso 9|(IE))]>
                     </v:textbox>
                     </v:rect>
                  <![endif]-->

               </td>
            </tr>
<!-- END BANNER -->

<!-- START GREEN COLUMN -->
            <tr>
               <td style="padding: 0;">
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0;" role="presentation">
                     <tr>
                        <td height="8" style="background-color: #60C1CB;"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
<!-- END GREEN COLUMN -->

<!-- START TWO COLUMN -->
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 35px 0 30px 0;">

                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0;" role="presentation">
                       <tr>
                          <td class="two-columns" style="padding: 0; font-size: 0; text-align: center;">
  
                             <!--[if (gte mso 9|(IE))]>
                                <table width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0;" role="presentation">
                                   <tr>
                                      <td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding: 0">
                             <![endif]-->
  
                             <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="column" style="border-spacing: 0; vertical-align: top; width: 100%; max-width: 300px; display: inline-block;" role="presentation">
                                <tr>
                                   <td class="padding" style="padding: 20px">
  
                                      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="content" style="border-spacing: 0; text-align: left;">
                                         <tr>
                                            <td>
                                               <a href="*" target="_blank"><img class="two-col-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/mvMkS3V/Aura-Enterprise-ENG-No-Logo.png" alt="Logo" width="260" border="0" style="max-width: 260px; border-radius: 8px;"></a>
                                            </td>
                                         </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                            <td style="padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;">
                                               <p style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 25px;">lorum lorum lorum</p>
                                               <p style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;">lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum.</p>
                                            </td>
                                         </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                            <td align="left" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                               <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" border="0" style="border-spacing: 0;" role="presentation">
                                                  <tr>
                                                     <td style="border-radius: 10px;" bgcolor="#60C1CB">
                                                        <a href="*" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; color: #ffffff; background-color: #60C1CB; border: 1px solid #60C1CB; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px 25px; display: inline-block; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">lorum</a>
                                                     </td>
                                                  </tr>
                                               </table>
                                            </td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </table>
  
                                   </td>
                                </tr>
                             </table>
  
                             <!--[if (gte mso 9|(IE))]>
                                </td><td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding: 0">
                             <![endif]-->
  
                             <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="column" style="border-spacing: 0; vertical-align: top; width: 100%; max-width: 300px; display: inline-block;" role="presentation">
                                <tr>
                                   <td class="padding" style="padding: 20px">
  
                                      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="content" style="border-spacing: 0; text-align: left;" role="presentation">
                                         <tr>
                                            <td>
                                               <a href="*" target="_blank"><img class="two-col-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/dmy8zRj/Aura-Enterprise-CYM-No-Logo.png" alt="Logo" width="260" border="0" style="max-width: 260px; border-radius: 8px;"></a>
                                            </td>
                                         </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                            <td style="padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;">
                                               <p style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 25px;">lorum lorum lorum</p>
                                               <p style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;">lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum.</p>
                                            </td>
                                         </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                            <td align="left" style="padding-left: 10px;">
  
                                               <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" border="0" style="border-spacing: 0;" role="presentation">
                                                  <tr>
                                                     <td style="border-radius: 10px;" bgcolor="#60C1CB">
                                                         <a href="*" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; color: #ffffff; background-color: #60C1CB; border: 1px solid #60C1CB; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px 25px; display: inline-block; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">lorum</a>
                                                     </td>
                                                  </tr>
                                               </table>
  
                                            </td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </table>
  
                                   </td>
                                </tr>
                             </table>
  
                             <!--[if (gte mso 9|(IE))]>
                                      </td>
                                   </tr>
                                </table>
                             <![endif]-->
  
                          </td>
                       </tr>
                    </table>
                 </td>
            </tr>
<!-- END TWO COLUMN -->

         </table>

         <!--[if (gte mso 9|(IE))]>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         <![endif]-->

      </div>

   </center>

</body>
```

I even tried changing the `width` and `height` to `pt` as the guide suggested but this made no difference.

Comment: You've got an issue there with the twitter link, `<a href="*"_blank">`

Comment: Ah sorry it must of been me deleting and replacing of my links with `*` as its fine in my code - I'll edit this post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked for me on my Outlook (Windows, 365) when I changed from px to pt. You also have to multiply by 0.75 of course. So it becomes:

```
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:450pt; height:247pt; border: 0; display: inline-block;">
```

Edit:
You also need to collapse the borders, which can be just done template-wide via the head. The default is separate table cells, which puts in a small gap between them.

```
<head>
<!--[if mso]>
  <style type="text/css">
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
  }
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, that's strange as its still not working for me even with `pt` so what I have done is edited my markup to give you more context just in case its the table rows above and below causing an issue.  Also I am wondering if its my real banner image `https://i.ibb.co/QKH3gst/Aura-banner.png` that is causing the gap as my markup in this post contains a placeholder.

Comment: You could try deleting all the sections except one or two, see if that fixes it, then add them in one by one. That will tell you which section is problematic. It could be that one other section is pushing the layout out. Perhaps there is an image or width too much for it- that will push the rest out.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks, I did what you said and it looks like the offending article is the `<!-- START TWO COLUMN -->` section as the spacing appears as soon as you put that markup in!  So I have amended my markup in my post with that section as I'm not sure what is causing it to do this.

Comment: Updated with fix

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I can't believe my eyes as after all these weeks there is no gap with my banner image!